# Alternatives to materialized view on Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, materialized-views

We need information based on a count of two tables in our Azure SQL database. Calculating this information every time this information is requested is expensive. We're looking into building a materialized view and we are wondering if there are alternatives. The only thing I can think of is creating a separate table and write a batch job which updates this information every night. The information may be 1 day old.

Are there better ways to do this? A materialized view is probably the easiest solution, but are there drawbacks to this solution?

Comment: Indexed Views are available in Azure SQL DB - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Any other alternatives to an indexed view? I see two big problems: The fact that the view gets updated every time a base table gets updated. And the fact that the code is in the database and not in a git repo.

Comment: Not sure I understand your points: the point of having a materialized or indexed view would be that it's up-to-date.  You could use also use a conventional view, the other two tend to be used when you can prove they bring a performance improvement.  Re the code not being in a repo - why isn't it in a repo?  It should be in a repo.

Comment: We work with a code first database. You can add entities to the dotnet project, but adding an indexed view seems more difficult.

Comment: Look, using an indexed view has almost nothing to do with your app-tier development mode.  Or, put in other terms, if you are going to go code-first and ignore the things the DB can do for you, then why care about performance?  Indexed views can have lock conflicts for high update workloads and that's the primary concern of using them.  Your alternative is to consider a non-clustered columnstore where batch mode aggregation is much faster and may remove the need to think about indexed views for your scenario.